# Dynamic lead capture script

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm creating a dynamic lead capture script.

The form passes the table name, and the rest of the post data.

I'm looking for a way to collect all the post inputs and insert that into a MySQL table without knowing the input names since each 'lead' script is different and contains different fields.

The table is already created and contains all the columns necessary for the input.

Any clean ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is to serialize an array of your validated post data. This will convert it into a string for storing in your Database.

You can unserialize that string to convert it back into a manageble array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

The biggest downside is not having the full SQL support that you would have otherwise, by putting data into separate database fields.

I would use a combination of both techniques by putting consistant data like names, email into their own fields and unknown data into another field.

--

Try index identification (if you don't know the specific names):

```
$data = array_values($_POST);

$name = $data[0];
$email = $data[1];
$etc = $data[2];
```

--

Generate SQL string from data. Remember be vigilant with validation and ideally you should use Mysqli bind params to correcly build your query string.

```
foreach($_POST as $input_name => $input_value){
    //do validation here

    //match columns here
    if($input_name=='name') $cleaned[$input_name] = $input_value;
}

$values_csv = '"'.implode('","',$cleaned).'"';

$sql  = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ($values_csv);";
```

Comment: I agree, and that downside is my issue, since the table is already built with separated fields, therefore I need to find a way to insert that data into the fields (basically the input name is the same as the mysql field name).

Comment: theres no way of knowing what the data is comes from what fields if you don't know the input name. You can test each inputted data for what it could be or identify the inputed data by its index - the position in the $_POST array. Is the index consistant?

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is like that:
I'm collecting all the inputs with array_keys($_POST); 
and then I have to find a way to set those on an sql query: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...) - Now I don't know how to set the columns and value data without looping.

Comment: looping is your only choice with building your own string query string. Use a combo of array_values/array_keys to get what you need. Note though that you should validate all your data - both keys and values. If you have a key that doesn't match a colomn name you will have an error with your query.

Comment: Not sure how to loop that, after all I need to execute 1 MySQL query with all the columns and their data (same order).

Comment: Well, before reading your post I tried something close myself:
$_POST = clean($_POST); 

$columns = join(',',array_keys($_POST));
$coldata = join(',',array_values($_POST));
$client = $_POST['client'];

Now the issue is that submit, and the client name, are values and keys as well, and I need to remove them from the array. figuring out how to do that now.

Comment: Cheers for the help man, I used a combination of the things and achieved the target, I appreciate your time!